# Are there any "complete" languages in $coNP -NP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np, co-np

Suppose $coNP \neq NP$

language B would be called "complete" in $coNP-NP$ if:

1. $B\in coNP - NP$
2. $A\in coNP-NP \implies  A\leq_pB$

Are there any "complete" languages in $coNP - NP$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are assuming that $coNP≠$,

we can conclude that every language that is $co
NP$ complete is **not in** $NP$ (a contradiction to your given assumption).

Thus, every language we already know of that is $coNP$ complete, is complete as well in $coNP -NP$.